# Null reference exception stops the code execution inside of try block

Tags: c#, visual-studio, try-catch, nullreferenceexception, npoi

So I have a code segment where I am expecting a method that is repeatedly called from inside a loop to return null at one point - null is returned because the table cell that this method tries to read from is empty. And that part is clear, that's not the problematic part of the behavior. Here is that part of code:

```
while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnI_value))
{
    typeOfShareLineCounter++;

    try
    {
        columnI_value = sheet.GetRow(3 + typeOfShareLineCounter + typeOfShareStartIndexNewFile).GetCell(8).ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why does program execution stop when an empty cell is reached in this case? I get NullReferenceException, but I am expecting the program to continue since the line of code where this exception occurs is inside the "try" block as you can see above.
Is it because of some Visual Studio setting?
As a side note, in a "normal" scenario, I could have probably just checked what the GetCell method returns and if it's null, just break out of the loop (because null in this case means that we have reached the end of the file segment that needs to be read).

However, GetCell here produces an exception in case the cell it is trying to read is empty. This is the reason I used the try-catch. But I was not expecting the program execution to halt in this case. At the moment, I do not see a way to handle the exception without it breaking the program. Btw, this problematic method (GetCell) is a part of the NPOI library for working with excel files.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Go To "Debug => Windows => Exception Settings" What is the value for the entry "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"?

Comment: Okay it is in try catch block but your while condition says when  columnI_value != null continue . You need to change your condition or replace scopes of while  & try catch block .

Comment: Please produce a simplified example that reproduces the issue. I tried: `string nullString = null;` and replaced in your code: `columnI_value = nullString.ToString();` (which should reproduce the error you're getting), and program execution never stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if something is null before trying to access it?
I think `GetCell` throws an exception because `GetRow` returns `null`.
Also not clear what value is initially in `columnI_value`.

I would use something like this (just guessing what this code is expected to do):

```cs
typeOfShareLineCounter = 0;

while (true)
{
    var cell = sheet.GetRow(3 + typeOfShareLineCounter + typeOfShareStartIndexNewFile)?.GetCell(8);
    if (cell == null)
        continue;

    columnI_value = cell.ToString();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnI_value))
        break;

    typeOfShareLineCounter++;
}
```